# How to calculate all possible combinations of two alphanumeric characters?

Tags: python, combinations, cartesian-product, alphabet, number-systems

Having an alphabet of letters *A-Z* and numbers *0-9*, how to get [all 1296 possible combinations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1331664/combinations-of-two-character-alphanumeric-how-many) like:

```
['AA', 'AB', ..., 'AZ', 'A0', 'A1', ..., 'Z9', '0A', '0B', ..., '98', '99']
```

As a side question, what is this type of number system called?

Comment: Use `itertools` [combinations with replacement](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement)

Answer (score 3):

Current suggestions are wrong. Combinations with replacement, for example,  won't give you `AB` and `BA` at the same time, only the first one. And `permutations` won't have `AA`, `BB`, etc.

Instead you should use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

For example:

```
import string
import itertools

combinations_generator = itertools.product(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, 
                                           repeat=2)
combinations = list(map(''.join, combinations_generator))
print(len(combinations))
```

This will give you exactly 1296 combinations.

`combinations_generator` will generate tuples like `('A', 'A')`, `('A', 'B')`, etc.
And with `map(''.join, combinations_generator)` we will join them together like `'AA'`, `'AB'`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [permutations](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) to get the list.

For example

```
import string
import itertools
series = [''.join(r) for r in itertools.permutations([str(i) for i in range(10)]+[str(c) for c in string.ascii_uppercase], 2)]
print(series)
print(len(series))  # got 1260 here
```

Comment: shouldn't it be 1296 combinations?

Comment: Oh, yes, then the series need to add AA BB CC DD.. 00 ...99, so you can just use 2 layer for loop to get the series , no need any built in functions